# Partial WinForm UI freeze when switching windows or apps via Windows taskbar for Excel VSTO

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel, progress-bar, vsto

I have a weird problem (possibly a threading issue) that has been troubling me. I would like to have a progress bar for a task that I run in Excel/VSTO, that is started by clicking a button on the ribbon.

Since all access to the Excel Object model must occur in the main thread, I show my progress form modally on a separate thread. This works great most of the time, but odd things happen when I switch apps or windows via the Windows task bar. For example, if I am in the middle of a run and Excel is maximized, and I click Chrome on my taskbar to give it focus, then I click back to Excel and click between open Excel workbooks in the taskbar previews, sometimes the UI will partially freeze in the progress bar.

In Excel 2007/2010, I can still see the progress bar being updated but I can't drag the toolbar or click the Cancel button; this is why I say the UI partially freezes. Similar stuff happens in Excel 2013/2016 but I haven't tested as much on them.

If Excel has focus and we don't switch to another window during the execution of the task, then the progress bars work perfectly.

Does anyone have an idea what could be going wrong?

Is there another way I can go about displaying the progress bar in Excel to give consistent and reliable behavior? Note the limitation that the actual task needs to run on the main Excel UI thread and that for a progress form to be interactive and display properly, it needs to be on a secondary UI thread. Because of this, solution like using a BackgroundWorker won't work.

```
class RunSampleProgressTask
{
    private ProgressForm _form;
    internal volatile bool CancelPending;
    internal volatile AutoResetEvent SignalEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    internal RunSampleProgressTask()
    {
        //create a new workbook
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        int hwnd = GetHwnd();

        var thread = new Thread(() => ShowProgressForm(hwnd));
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        thread.Name = "ProgressFormThread";
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();

        SignalEvent.WaitOne();

        //In SDI Excel a newly created workbook won't be shown until the function ends so we use a timer to show the new workbook before running Run()
        if (IsSDI) 
            ExecuteTaskIn(200,Run);
        else
            Run();
    }

    internal static void ExecuteTaskIn(int milliseconds, Action action)
    {
        var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            ((System.Windows.Forms.Timer)s).Stop(); //s is the Timer
            action();
        };
        timer.Interval = milliseconds;
        timer.Start();
    }

    //returns true if it is Excel 2013 or 2016 that use the new Single Document Interface
    public static bool IsSDI 
    {
        get
        {
            string appVersion = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Version;
            return appVersion.StartsWith("15") || appVersion.StartsWith("16");
        }
    }

    private void ShowProgressForm(int hwnd)
    {
        _form = new ProgressForm(this) {StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen};
        _form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        _form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        _form.ShowDialog(new Win32Window(hwnd));
    }

    protected void ReportProgress(int percent)
    {
        if (_form == null || !_form.IsHandleCreated) return;
        _form.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _form.SetProgress(percent)));
    }

    protected void CloseForm()
    {
        if (_form == null || !_form.IsHandleCreated) return;
        _form.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _form.Close()));
    }

    internal static int GetHwnd()
    {
        if (IsSDI)
        {
            var window = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow;
            int hwnd = (int)window.GetType().InvokeMember("Hwnd", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, window, null); //late binding call to get Window.Hwnd
            return hwnd;
        }
        else
        {
            return Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd;
        }
    }

    private const int BufRowSize = 16384;  //must be a factor of RowsPerPage
    private const int RowsPerPage = 1048576;
    private const int BufColSize = 10;
    private const int Repetitions = 80;
    internal void Run()
    {
        ReportProgress(0);


        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.EnableEvents = false;

        var buf = new string[BufRowSize, BufColSize];

        //fill the buffer with sample data
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < BufRowSize; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < BufColSize; j++)
                buf[i, j] = "String" + (++cnt);

        var workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
        var sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

        int currRow = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < Repetitions; i++)
        {
            if (CancelPending)
            {
                CloseForm();
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating = true;
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.EnableEvents = true;
                return;
            }
            sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[currRow, 1], sheet.Cells[currRow + BufRowSize - 1, BufColSize]].Value2 = buf;

            currRow += BufRowSize;
            if (currRow > RowsPerPage)
            {
                currRow = 1;
                sheet = workbook.Sheets.Add(Missing.Value, sheet);
            }
            int percent = 100 * (i + 1) / Repetitions;
            ReportProgress(percent);
        }

        CloseForm();
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating = true;
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.EnableEvents = true;
    }
}

public partial class ProgressForm : Form
{
    private ProgressBar _progressBar;
    private Label _lblStatus;
    private Button _btnCancel;

    private RunSampleProgressTask _task;

    internal ProgressForm(RunSampleProgressTask task)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Width = 320;
        this.Height = 120;
        this.ControlBox = false;
        _task = task;
        _progressBar = new ProgressBar(){Left=10, Top = 10, Width= 300, Height = 30};
        _lblStatus = new Label(){Left = 10, Top = 50};
        _btnCancel = new Button(){Text = "Cancel", Left = _lblStatus.Right + 10, Top = 50, Width = 100};
        _btnCancel.Click += _btnCancel_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(_progressBar);
        this.Controls.Add(_lblStatus);
        this.Controls.Add(_btnCancel);

        this.Shown += ProgressForm_Shown;
    }

    void ProgressForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _task.SignalEvent.Set();
    }

    void _btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _task.CancelPending = true;
        _lblStatus.Text = "Cancelling...";
    }

    internal void SetProgress(int percent)
    {
        _progressBar.Value = percent;
        _lblStatus.Text = percent + "%";
    }
}

public class Win32Window : IWin32Window
{
    public Win32Window(int hwnd)
    {
        Handle = new IntPtr(hwnd);
    }

    public Win32Window(IntPtr handle)
    {
        Handle = handle;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: the thread priority is not the problem. I originally had it on its default (ThreadPriority.Normal) and the problem still occurred. I only switched it to Highest as a test to see if the extra CPU cycles would prevent the UI freeze, which it didn't.

Comment: did you tried and get any final solution?